# How do I refresh a Smartcar access token?

Tags: node.js, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, automotive

I use the Smartcar API on my Tesla (https://teslaapi.dev/) and successfully made a request before but I think the access token expired and I don't know how to refresh it.

I followed this guide: https://smartcar.com/docs/integration-guides/express/request/ 
It talks about the access token but it doesn't tell me how to get the refresh token.

```
// ./index.js

app.get('/vehicle', function(req, res) {
    // TODO: Request Step 2: Get vehicle information
    return smartcar.getVehicleIds(access.accessToken)
      .then(function(data) {
        // the list of vehicle ids
        return data.vehicles;
      })
      .then(function(vehicleIds) {
        // instantiate the first vehicle in the vehicle id list
        const vehicle = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleIds[0], access.accessToken);

        return vehicle.info();
      })
    .then(function(info) {
      res.render('vehicle', {
        info: info,
      });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work anymore:
    {
      "error": "authentication_error",
      "message": "Invalid or expired token provided."
    }

I think it's because I need to replace the accessToken with a refresh token. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

So your hunch about needing to use the refresh token is correct.

If you look at the ["Request access token"](https://smartcar.com/docs/api#request-access-token) section of API Reference, it notes that the access tokens are only valid for 2 hours, after that point you'll need to use the refresh token to get a new access token to use.

If you're using the Node SDK, you can use the [`exchangeRefreshToken`](https://github.com/smartcar/node-sdk/tree/master/doc#AuthClient+exchangeRefreshToken) method to exchange your refresh token for a new set of tokens.

Here's an example with all of that integrated:

```
// ./index.js

app.get('/vehicle', function(req, res) {
    if (smartcar.isExpired(acccess.expiration)) {
      const 
   }

    // TODO: Request Step 2: Get vehicle information
    return smartcar.getVehicleIds(access.accessToken)
      .then(function(data) {
        // the list of vehicle ids
        return data.vehicles;
      })
      .then(function(vehicleIds) {
        // instantiate the first vehicle in the vehicle id list
        const vehicle = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleIds[0], access.accessToken);

        return vehicle.info();
      })
    .then(function(info) {
      res.render('vehicle', {
        info: info,
      });
    });
});
```

For a proper long term implementation of this you'll need to involve some sort of database that stores the access object based on vehicle id.